# How to assign a specific date to a textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a jQuery function that assigns today's date to a textbox when a radio button is clicked.

In the example below, when the radio button value is "I", the Date Inactive date is today. When the radio button value is "A", the Date Active date is also today.

I am trying to introduce another action: when the radio button value is "A" I want to make id DNE to be equal to "12-31" of the current year (so in this case, "12-31-2016").

Since I wasn't sure how to do that, I entered ??? as the value. Thanks for any help.

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + '-' +  (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
};

$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
  $(".Status").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == "I")
       $("#Date_Inactive").val(d.yyyymmdd());
     if ($(this).val() == "A")
       $("#Date_Accepted").val(d.yyyymmdd());
       $("#DNE").val(???);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please learn to use your Developer Console. It's built just for you to spot and kind errors and make your programming fun.

Answer (score 0):

P.S: notice that you're missing an `(` in

```
return yyyy + '-' +  (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' +   dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); 
                                    // Missing ( ^^^ HERE
```

Otherwise:

```
$("#DNE").val( d.yyyymmdd().substring(5, 10) );
```

```js
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
  return yyyy + '-' +  (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
};



$(function(){
  
  var d = new Date();
  
  $(".Status").change(function () {
    
    if ($(this).val() == "I")
      $("#Date_Inactive").val( d.yyyymmdd() );
    
    if ($(this).val() == "A")
      $("#Date_Accepted").val( d.yyyymmdd() );
    
    $("#DNE").val( d.yyyymmdd().substring(5, 10) );
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="dateRadio" value="I" class="Status">
<input type="radio" name="dateRadio" value="A" class="Status">
<br>
<input type="text" id="Date_Inactive"> inactive <br>
<input type="text" id="Date_Accepted"> accepted<br>
<input type="text" id="DNE">DNE
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do it without the func - here you go:

```
$("#DNE").val('12-31-'+new Date().getFullYear());
```